# How to convert a stream to another type without using map?

Tags: flutter, dart

I've this code:

```dart
Stream<int> get fooStream async* {
  barStream.listen((_) async* { 
    int baz = await getBaz();
    yield baz; // Does not work
  });  
}
```

How can I return `Stream<int>` from another stream?

---

**Note**: If I use `map` to transform the stream, then I'll have to return `Stream<Future<int>>`, but I want to return `Stream<int>`. I also don't feel like using `rxdart` pacakge for this tiny thing.

Comment: `Stream.asyncMap` - the docs say: *"Creates a new stream with each data event of this stream asynchronously mapped to a new event.

This acts like map, except that convert may return a Future, and in that case, this stream waits for that future to complete before continuing with its result."*

Comment: @pskink Thank you, I forgot to check if there's something like `asyncMap` exist, and this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use `asyncMap`.

   ```dart
   barStream.asyncMap((e) => getBaz())
   ```
2. Use `await for`

   ```dart
   Stream<int> get fooStream async* {
    await for (final item in barStream) {
      yield await getBaz();
    }
   }
   ```

Comment: StackOverflow formatting is so hard

Comment: Haha, and I figured out I could have also used `StreamController` for this.

Comment: StreamController should be disposed, so `await for` is better.

Comment: Of course, your solution is better, but I was just saying that can also work.

Comment: Also, I checked that asyncExpand and asyncMap are part of dart library. So you could also use them

Comment: I have edited it to be asyncMap @pskink